# Reference common Javascript file in two solutions

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, build, bundle, web-parts

/

..Common/Scripts/Script1.js

..Sharepoint2010/Layout/Scripts/[reference to Script1.js]

..Sharepoint2013/Layout/Scripts/[reference to Script1.js]

Developement for Sharepoint allows to deploy resources such as js and css files.
Different versions of Sharepoint have different metadata (project types, webparts, paths), but the source js/css are the same.

Programmatically it's best to have a signle copy of resource and *use* it from these different projects.

So editing Script1 in Sharepoint2010 project and saving it eventually result in updated Common/Script1.js which will be i.e. updated automatically for Sharepoint2013.

I'm relatively new to sharepoint, but I'm not searching for "use build options, cmd xcopy /sp2010/script1.js common/scripts/script1.js".

I'm using WebEssentials to simplify development, there are bundles, which defines path to resources and then compile these resources, but that doesn't work with the given scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, ["Add as link" option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714082%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in Visual Studio can help you. The article is actually about Win8 development, but whatever.